# Open/Export PDB File

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro, typeconverter, pdb-files

I have a working application that is using a PDB file as data source. Due to that application is not doing all what the customer wants, I need to know how I can read/write the information from the PDB file.
It doesn't matter if I have to export it to another format and then start working in the new format (csv,xls,mysql, MS sql), I don't need to keep updated the source file.

I tried a lots of converters and different way to read the information but I was not able to do it.

The current programs is build by Visual Fox Pro, and there are several dbf file that I could open and see the table information, but I still cannot access to the PDB file that I think has ALL the information. Each file (dbf and pdb) have their corresponding cdx file.

Comment: "PDB" is not a self-explaining data-file extension in a (Visual) FoxPro context. One among other options could be that your "PDB" is just a renamed "DBF" table file, so that your existing code would for example use FoxPro's `USE` command in order to open the file

Comment: It'd be helpful if you open a pdb file with a hex editor and attach a screenshot.

Comment: As Stefan mentioned, I too have seen times when a developer creates a table with an explicitly different file name extension.  You could try opening it in VFP from the command window by specifically including the suffix such as...  "Use YourTable.PDB"  or with the path "Use [C:\Some Path\YourTable.PDB".  But PDB is associated with C++ as Program Debug information, so unsure if this file is really what you want.

Comment: Thanks to both, I change the extension and I was able to open the table directly.. Please add your answer so I can mark as the correct one.
Anyway, when I open the database I see that all the information is encrypted so I create a new question. I will be glad if you could help me there too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823726/how-to-dencrypt-an-string-encrypted-by-v-foxpro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"PDB" is not a self-explaining data-file extension in a (Visual) FoxPro context. One among other options could be that your "PDB" is just a renamed "DBF" table file, so that your existing code could for example use FoxPro's `USE` command in order to open the file.

You would not even need to change the extension of the possible shared file back to default, Command Window example:

```
CD d:\temp && optionally determine your working folder
CREATE TABLE test.pdb (col1 Int) && non-default file extension
USE && close the new table
USE test && open attempt fails caused by unexpected extension ('File "name" does not exist (Error 1)')
USE test.pdb && works
BROWSE
```